# Detect the category of a product from product attributes using AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have a list of products (700,000+) in an excel file and I want to import this data to my database.

On my system, each product should be assigned a category and I want to develop an importer desktop application that loops on all the products and can detect the category of each product based on the values in the excel sheet.

The excel sheet product details are:Title, Description, Brand, Manufacturer, Features

I am looking for an AI solution that can learn progressively by experience, where I can teach him the keywords for each category to use in the matching decision.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say if Neural Networks would be the ideal approach for the data given, or the number of categories that you are trying to break it down to.

I suspect that you would need to do a lot of pre-processing to get the data into a format that would be trainable by a neural network.

If you are looking for an AI-Type approach that may categorise the information, perhaps some kind of rule-based approach (like Decision Trees) may assist such that it builds the rules based on trainable data:

```
If Features Include X Then
  If Title Contains Y Then
    Category is A
  Else
    Category is B
  End If
Else
  Category is C
End If
```